# How can I fix Option + E not working on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

Recently my MacBook has stoped displaying the ´ when I hit Option + e. I can't even press the ´ in the keyboard viewer.

The others accents are working without any problems.

Anyone have any ideas to solve for this, how might  I reset all keyboard shortcuts on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

The procedure in the comments helped to solve my problem with key combinations:

> Option+E is controlled by your keyboard layout, it is not a shortcut. It is possible that some application you have recently installed is using this combination. Did you install any software recently? One check you can do is to go the Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources and check the "show input menu in the menu bar" checkbox and in Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard check the "Show Keyboard, Emoji & Symbol Viewer" option. Then in the menubar click on the keyboard layout icon and select Show Keyboard Viewer. Now if you press option it should highlight all special characters you can type.

In my case, Speechify was using the combination.