# Option + E accent not working on Google Chrome - Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, catalina

A few days ago my Macbook stopped displaying the ´ character when I use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

The same happens if I try to use the ´ in the keyboard viewer.

Option u and option n work to make umlaut and tilde as expected.

Catalina 10.15.4, input sources US and US International PC.

Everything else is working as usual. I tried the options suggested in this question
[Option + E not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214000/option-e-not-working) but nothing changed.

Anyone have any ideas what may be happening? I haven't installed anything new either.

**Edit:** This seems to only be happening in Google Chrome

Comment: If you hold down the 'e' key, does the accent menu pop up to show you the available accents? BTW/ which version of macOS?

Comment: Which language source are you using?  I just tested with English/USA and it works as expected, but in Spanish, it doesn't

Comment: @IconDaemon I have macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and yeah when holding e I see the accents in the pop up, just option+e is not working

Comment: @Allan I am using the same English/USA, tried changing to english/U.S. International and others but didn't solve it

Comment: @TomGewecke I have two options for English/U.S. and English/U.S. International in input sources, other commands like option+u (ü), option+n (ñ) work as expected, only option+e doesn't

Comment: When you have US International seleted in the flag menu at the top right of the screen, you can make acute accent by just typing ' and then the base letter.  Does that work?

Comment: Does this problem with acute happen in all apps including Mail, Safari, Notes, Message, TextEdit, Pages?  If you change the font?

Comment: @TomGewecke Using acute with U.S. International works, thank you, I didn't know that option. and I also just noticed that it doesn't happen in Safari or other apps, just Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After realizing the problem only happened in Chrome I disabled extensions and the accent option worked again.

The extension responsible is **Honorlock** if someone else runs with the same problem.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this problem also happened to me with **Grammarly**. After disabling it, both characters were available again.

System details:

- MacOs Catalina 10.15.7
- Chrome 87.0.4280.88